# How do I upload multiple images to 1 record directly to s3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, image-uploading, jquery-file-upload

I have a `Product` model and for each record created, I want multiple images associated with that record (say 3 - 10). Each image should have multiple sizes (say 3 different sizes).

I checked out Carrierwave and that works - but just for 1 image (or rather, I can't figure out how to get multiple images for 1 record).

I also looked at jQuery File Upload and that seems to allow the easy upload of multiple files, but it ultimately comes down to each upload is associated with 1 record. So, yes you can drag and drop files, but if you drag 5 files you have created 5 records.

Ideally, I would like to be able to get the same jQuery-File-Upload functionality (where processing is done on the client-side, progress bars are shown during upload, drag & drop if possible, etc.) but just allowing all the images being uploaded at once, to be assigned to 1 record.

Thanks.

Comment: I've (almost) struggled with this before ... You're going to need either multiple columns or a separate model for your images. Found https://github.com/kdironside/carrierwave-multi-file-upload as an example app with Gallery / Photo style models. Shouldn't be too hard to implement the nested form either.

Comment: Well, I came across that and it looks good. The issue is that, in that case the gallery has multiple photos and each photo corresponds to a unique record in the gallery. That's not quite the same thing. I am using Carrierwave and I want to associate multiple images/photos with 1 unique Product record. Just haven't figured out how to do that quite yet.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding the difference ... my apologies. Do you have a public project on github at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can store serialized parameters in database, so you'll store all your images in 1 column. However better solution would be create new model that belongs to your parent model and your parent has_many :new_model

Comment: Carrierwave already creates a new model - so how do I do what you suggested while using Carrierwave?

Comment: carrier wave doesnt make new model. It makes new uploader which you month in your model. And there you could try to serialize params

Comment: I didn't realize that I should make another model called `Uploads` or `Images` and mount Carrierwave to that.